# Infinite composition of automorphisms.

Tags: uniform-convergence, function-and-relation-composition

When is it meaningful to talk about a countably infinite composition of automorphisms of a given object? I'm assuming such infinite compositions exist since (correct me if I'm wrong) but an infinite composition of the identity map would give the identity map.

This question came up in the following context:

> Let $C$ be the canonical Cantor set and let $C_\alpha$ be a Cantor-type set, i.e. the same construction but removing the middle $\alpha$-interval at each iteration instead of the middle third. Prove "stuff"...

I wanted to prove the "stuff" by showing existence of an order preserving homeomorphism $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ with $f(C) = C_\alpha$.

The series of composite automorphisms $\{\varphi_k\}$ would certainly need some convergence properties. But I'm hoping for some examples or contexts in which such infinite compositions would arise (or not).

In particular, when does an infinite composition of automorphisms produce another automorphism?

-XXP

Comment: Infinite composition of automorphisms doesn't exist in general. Take for example the automorphism that takes the complex number $z$ to its conjugate. There is no pleasant way to define the infinite composition of this with itself.

Comment: Note that it's not difficult to find examples where the composition is meaningless or doesn't converge to an automorphism. But I would like to know if/when it is meaningful.

Comment: @XXP maybe in Liegroups like $O(n)$ or something like that

Comment: The answerd given so far give examples where the limit can hardly be defined or where the limit (according to pointwise convergence) exists but fails to be an automorphism. Are there also examples where the limit exists, but is not even a homomorphism?

Answer (score 0):

Those composition don't need to converge in some sense. Take for example the real numbers with addition as a group. Then the mappling $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}; \ x\mapsto \frac{x}2$ is an automorphism. As $f^k : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} ; \ x\mapsto \frac{x}{2^k}$ the composition converges to the constant 0 function.

Maybe you are looking for [Lie-groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group)
which are -saying heuristical (as I only know them in that way)- manifolds which are a group too
and have a differential group operation. So for example $SO(2)$ is a Lie group, those are the 
rotations on $\mathbb{R}^2$. This group is diffeomorphic to $S^1$ which is the unit ball in 
$\mathbb{R}^2$. Furthermore the composition of two rotations is just adding the angles, and 
a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is uniquely determined by the angle of its rotation. So as 
$S^1$ is a closed subspace of a Banach-space the infinite composition of rotations should
converge to a rotation when the infinite composition converges pointwise.

Comment: @XXP I am fully aware of this, i just wanted to give an example for which the limit of automorphism isn't an automorphism, although it exists

Comment: I understand, I misread your response. Apologies.